# How to launch a specific project from Visual Studio solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a solution which includes several projects. How can I launch each project from Visual Studio separately?

Comment: Or you could see step-by-step guid [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/10/multiple-startup-projects-vstipenv0015.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can configure a solution to have multiple startup projects - Right click the solution in Solution Explorer, choose "Set StartUp projects", choose "Multiple Startup Projects", and choose the ones you wish to have start. They'll all be started when you hit F5.

Or, you can right click any project in Solution Explorer, and choose "Debug"->"Start New Instance" or "Debug"->"Step Into New Instance" - you can do this to any projects you want to, at any time. (So, if you want to have some projects start when you start debugging, and start others at a later point, this is the way to go)

Comment: brilliant, plane and simple.

Answer (score 18):

Right click your solution and choose "set startup projects"

[image: startup projects]

next, you can choose which projects you want to start simultaniously

[image: startup overview]

or you could right click a project and set that one to startup, each time you "F5", that one will start. You can verify which one is set as startup by looking at the one in bold.

Answer (score 6):

You can also select the option `Set StartUp Projects...>Current Selection`. To run the project you have in editor window.

Answer (score 1):

You could select a default startup project for the solution in the menu if you right click on it. This could also be done if you right click on the solution and go to the properties window where you could select a single or multiple startup projects.