# I have multiple projects in one Visual Basic solution, how do I start the other project when I press a button?

Tags: vba

I have multiple projects in one Visual Basic solution, how do I start the other project when I press a button? I want to press a button that launches the other project in the solution. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a specific project from Visual Studio solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5256945/11683)

Comment: No, that is different!

Comment: Then you need to explain the problem better.